# biblatex prints "family=, familyi=" etc. in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

My aim is to use BiBLaTeX with the numeric-comp style and family-given/given-family way of sorting author's names, with all names in bold. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
sorting=none,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
        \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
        {\ifgiveninits
            {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
                {\namepartfamily}
                {\namepartgiveni}
                {\namepartprefix}
                {\namepartsuffix}}
            {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
                {\namepartfamily}
                {\namepartgiven}
                {\namepartprefix}
                {\namepartsuffix}}%
            \ifboolexpe{%
                test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
                and
                test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
            {}
            {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
        {\ifgiveninits
            {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
                {\namepartfamily}
                {\namepartgiveni}
                {\namepartprefix}
                {\namepartsuffix}}
            {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
                {\namepartfamily}
                {\namepartgiven}
                {\namepartprefix}
                {\namepartsuffix}}}%
        \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}

    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family-bold}

    \DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family-bold}
    \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{given-family-bold}
    \DeclareNameAlias{translator}{given-family-bold}

    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
        @book{Doe86,
            author = {Doe, John},
            year = {1986},
            title = {some book},
        }
    \end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

I'm citing \cite{Doe86}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Strangely, it produces the following ouput, no matter how often I compile (both latex and biber). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: @moewe, thanks, it looks normal again and is so much better for its shortness! It's weird that the other one doesn't work because I copy-pasted the code from one of your answers. Could it be a version issue?
However, now the 'family-given/given-family' sorting is not maintained, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a current version of `biblatex` I would use name wrappers to apply the boldface to the names. If you want the mixed `family-given/given-family` order, you still need to redefine the name format as well (because the default for numeric styles is `given-family` order).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
I'm citing \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: **Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde**. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//**Nussbaum, Martha**. Aristotle’s “De Motu Animalium”. Princeton: Princeton University Press, 1978. (bold text marked with double asterisks)]

---

The problem with the code from the question was that it defined one name format (`family-given/given-family-bold`), but then *used* a different, non-existing format (`given-family-bold`). Non-existing formats result in the weird output you got. The could could be reworked as follows (but I still prefer the solution above).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family-bold}{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
      {\ifgiveninits
          {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
              {\namepartfamily}
              {\namepartgiveni}
              {\namepartprefix}
              {\namepartsuffix}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
              {\namepartfamily}
              {\namepartgiven}
              {\namepartprefix}
              {\namepartsuffix}}%
          \ifboolexpe{%
              test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
              and
              test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
          {}
          {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
      {\ifgiveninits
          {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
              {\namepartfamily}
              {\namepartgiveni}
              {\namepartprefix}
              {\namepartsuffix}}
          {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
              {\namepartfamily}
              {\namepartgiven}
              {\namepartprefix}
              {\namepartsuffix}}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family-bold}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
I'm citing \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.